# Best approach text file to grouped csv by tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a file looking like this:

```
DOWNLOADPRINTER
S
CCODEPAGE 4103
CPAGENAME PAGE
CR_PAGE_INFO_START
FAVOURITE_FOOD Cookies
FAVOURITE_CAR AUDI
CR_PAGE_INFO_END
CR_ADDR_LINE_BEGIN
Adress_Post_code 1234
Adress_City GeorgeTown
CR_ADDR_LINE_END
CR_PERSONAL_INFO_START
FIRST_NAME John
LAST_NAME Doe
CR_PERSONAL_INFO_END
CR_ADDR_LINE_BEGIN
Adress_Post_code 1234
Adress_City GeorgeTown
CR_ADDR_LINE_END
CR_PERSONAL_INFO_START
FIRST_NAME Jane
LAST_NAME Doe
CR_PERSONAL_INFO_END
CR_ADDR_LINE_BEGIN
...
(random amount of datas, attributes have always same sort and amount)
...
CR_PERSONAL_INFO_END
DOWNLOADPRINTER
S
CCODEPAGE 4103
CPAGENAME PAGE
CR_PAGE_INFO_START
FAVOURITE_FOOD Donuts
FAVOURITE_CAR AUDI
CR_PAGE_INFO_END
CR_ADDR_LINE_BEGIN
Adress_Post_code 1234
Adress_City GeorgeTown
CR_ADDR_LINE_END
CR_PERSONAL_INFO_START
FIRST_NAME Jennifer
LAST_NAME Doe
```

The file contains about 10.000 datas in 1000 datasets each

I want to group it by different attributes to a correct looking csv with following format:

```
FAVOURITE_FOOD , FAVOURITE CAR, Adress_Post_code, Adress_City,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME 
Cookies, Audi, 1234, GeorgeTown, John, Doe
Cookies, Audi, 1234, GeorgeTown, Jane, Doe
......
Donuts, Audi, 1234, GeorgeTown, Jennifer, Doe
```

Aim is to ignore all arguments:
CR_..,
DOWNLOADPRINTER,
(the line) S,
CCODEPAGE.

Special argument is the favoutine_food and favourite_car which appears once in every dataset but has to be a prefix for each row at the particular dataset.

CURRENT APPROACH:

```
import csv
import os
import re
path = os.path.dirname(file)
filename = '/input.TXT'
output = 'output.csv'
attributes = ('FAVOURITE_FOOD', 'FAVOURITE_CAR', 'Adress_Post_code', 'Adress_City', 'FIRST_NAME','LAST_NAME' )

##dont parse all for testing
num_lines = 5000

with open(path + filename, 'r') as file:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(attributes)
        for i in range(num_lines):
            line = next(file).strip()
            if str(line).startswith('FAVOURITE_FOOD'):
                prefix = ''
                print('new dataset found')
                prefix = re.sub('FAVOURITE_FOOD', '', line)
                print(prefix)
                continue
            if str(line).startswith('FAVOURITE_CAR'):
                prefix += ',' + re.sub('FAVOURITE_CAR', '', line)
                print(prefix)
                continue
            if str(line).startswith('Adress_City'):
                line = re.sub('DWA_CO_ADDRESS-CITY1', '', line)
                ##dont allow whitespaces
                line = re.sub(' ', '', line)
                out_file.write(prefix + line)
                ##how to continue with the other files?
                ##I would like to stick with writer.writerow  and not  out_file.write
```

Comment: If you have a working solution now and want an *opinion* about a potential/hypothetical "better" solution, I recommend asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a `csv.writer` you must build a list per each row. The 2 first elements will be common to a bunch of rows. I would suggest that you use some of the *ignored* elements as sentinel values to know when a new row/group of rows starts and ends. That way you feed a row each time you find a relevant field and write it into your file when you find the sentinel line:

```
...
##dont parse all for testing
num_lines = 5000

sentinel = 'CR_PERSONAL_INFO_END'
reset = 'CR_PAGE_INFO_START'

# BEWARE do not forget newline='' for csv writers
with open(path + filename, 'r') as file, open(output, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    _ = writer.writerow(attributes)  # write headers
    row = ['' for at in attributes]  # prepare an empty row
    for i, line in enumerate(file):  # loop
        if i >= num_lines:           # a maximum of num_lines times
            break
        line = line.strip()
        if line == reset:           # reset attributes
            row = ['' for j in range(6)]
        elif line == sentinel:
            _ = writer.writerow(row)         # write a row
            row[2:] = ['' for j in range(4)] # and reset fields but 2 first ones
        else:
            fields = line.split()
            try:
                # search beginning of line in attributes
                ix = attributes.index(fields[0])
                row[ix] = fields[1]   # if found set second part in current row
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

With your example data if gives as expected:

```
FAVOURITE_FOOD,FAVOURITE_CAR,Adress_Post_code,Adress_City,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
Cookies,AUDI,1234,GeorgeTown,John,Doe
Cookies,AUDI,1234,GeorgeTown,Jane,Doe
Donuts,AUDI,1234,GeorgeTown,Jennifer,Doe
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it was very clear! As experienced stackoverflow User - could you may state why he post got downvoted? Anything I did completely wrong?

Comment: @Felix: You got one single downvote. It is always hard to guess why another user choosed to upvote or downvote. I have seen much worse posts which were not downvoted. Better to forget about it...